# Search through comma separated value using Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have product table which has field called search tags. In this field it has different type of values related to product which is separated by comma. (Like product product title ,brand, manufacturer, color etc.)

Ex. -

Product Title: Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max

Brand : Apple

Color : Red

So search tag will look like this -> apple iphone 12 pro max, apple, red

Now, suppose user search like this -> "iphone 12", "apple red", "apple 12" than in the result this product should appear.

I have tried MySQL FIND_IN_SET and LIKE operator but doesn't get expected output. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try  ->whereRaw("find_in_set('".$search."',column)")

Comment: i have tried that find_in_set only works if user search exact same keyword. it doesn't work if user  search nearly keyword.

Comment: are you sure like not working with you

Comment: I apply the same example from my side using like and its working

Comment: you store data inside column as string or json ?

Comment: yes I have tried but like not working. if you can post a demo query here so it will be helpful for me.

Comment: as a comma separated string.

Comment: select * from table where column like "%iphone%";

Comment: $model->where('column','like',"%$search%")

Comment: no this is not working as expected.

Comment: if its with comma seperated you can try using  IN   

Select * from table where  table.CommaseperatedColumn in (select CommaseperatedColumn from table )

this shoud work. but we will need more information to help any further. how is your database stractured ? what tables do you have etc

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLhxL.png  ~ this is demo how my product table look like.

Answer (score 0):

Does this Help at all?  my search criteria here was Apple Red , and the result was Iphone 12 RED

```
SELECT model FROM test
where test.phone in 
( select phone from test
 where phone like '%apple red%')
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/874tUw2TvbUAUqMFZX9Ly6/0)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what is if user searches "iphone red" ?

Comment: well if its in your comma-separated column it will find it, it searches inside that column and returns all the records that have  iphone red  in their comma separated column

Comment: let me know if you have any other questions. also if  this works for you please accept it as answer so it can help others in the future